# please some help solve this math statistics question

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, descriptive-statistics

(#9.116 full question on picture thanks in advance)

[question & info here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5GIm.jpg)

(if u cant read question part on  picture)
assume the underlying population is normal and = 2 pounds. Is there any evidence to suggest that the true mean weight of the blocks is different from 40 pounds? Use = 0.05 and compute the p value to draw a conclusion

Comment: You have got to be kidding. Can't read that tiny distorted picture. Please copy the relevant material into LaTeX in the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

x-bar = sum of data / n (8) = 40.9125

z score = 40.9125-40 (hypothesized mean) / (2/sqrt(8)) = 1.29047

Using the z-table we find that sample would only be in the 90.14 percentile of all possible samples (p-value of .0984 *2= .1971), so our p-value is not significant at the .05 level.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math on MSE see 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).